# R Looping with an if statement having to do with object existence

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Hypothetically, what is the logic of a loop with a if statement where the test expression is "when the object is run and it exists, do code A", else "do code b"? How to run a for loop have run an object and have the loop continue to the if statement without breaking. Thoughts?

```
for(i in 1:10){
code
object<- code
if (object doesn't exist){
code A
} 
else{ 
code B
}
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `if (!exists("object")) {`?

Comment: You posit `code` and assign that to object -- is`code` yielding a different result depending on `i`, where that result might or might not be `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, the first code is where [i] would be handled.

Comment: I'm confused about how to run the loop with the object not being defined until moment right before the if statement. Like I wouldn't be able to like define a css selector outside the loop if the page refreshes during the loop, but if you define the object before the if statement then the loop breaks.

Comment: *"run the loop with the object not being defined until moment right before the if statement"* ... `if (exists("object")) { ... } else { ... }`. That is, if you define `quux <- 1:10`, then `exists("quux")` will return `TRUE` (and would have been `FALSE` before that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration but I'd prefer this be more pithy.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  if (i == 2) {a <- "TWO!"} else { if (exists("a")) rm(a) }

  if(!exists("a")) {
    message("i: ", i, " and a doesn't exist")
  } else {
    message("i: ", i, " and a is ", a)
  }
}


#i: 1 and a doesn't exist
#i: 2 and a is TWO!
#i: 3 and a doesn't exist
#i: 4 and a doesn't exist
```

`a` doesn't exist within the loop until defined when `i == 2`. Then next time around I remove it.

Consequently, when we get to the section with the messages we can separately deal with whether `a` exists, and output accordingly.